# LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line

Tags: biblatex

I write the shortest code I can to cite and print bibliographies on Texmaker and texLive2020 as shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}
\begin{document}
read \cite{marcus}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with its respective citations.bib file.

```
@book{marcus,
author={Mitchell P. Marcus},
title={Switching circuits for engineers},
year={1975},
publisher={Prentince hall}}
```

But I always get the message "Empty bibliography" and a document without my bibliography.
I show a screenshot of some things that I have done. I have run the console and typed `biber file`. I have changed Bib(la)tex to `bibtex` `biber` `bibtex.exe` `biber.exe` `bibtex8.exe` `bibtexu.exe` all in its respective *"C:/texlive/2020/bin/win32/biber.exe" %* directory.

[image]

I really don't want to use *\begin{thebibliography}{9}\bibtem{m..}* because my bibliography can be to extensive and repetitive in some of my documents where I really could use this simplifying tool (that is why I use latex).
I've been days struggling with this, I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you run the normal cycle: `latex > biber >latex (twice)`?

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. I have done some combinations in the terminal, including ```biber file``` many times.

Comment: It's the main file that you have to compile, first with (pdf)latex, to create the necessary .aux file, that biber (or bibtex) will use in the second compilation, and last , to resolve all cross-references you have to compile with pdflatex again (twice). the compilation with thee bibliography engine should create a `.blg` file (the log file for bibliographies).

Comment: Now thank you very much! I have unchecked *use a "build" subdirectory for output files* where such ```.blg``` file was created and following the necesary compilation order my bibliography is finally printed. Thank you very much, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Those 'build' directories usually cause much more trouble than they do good. The whole LaTeX ecosystem assumes that temporary files are put into the same directory as your main `.tex` file. If you change that by using a 'build' subdirectory, many tools will need additional help to figure out where their configuration files are. Some might be completely unable to deal with such a situation.